# No sign change found error in R but not excel

Tags: r, excel, newtons-method

Just trying to understand why when I find the root of the following equation in excel I get a value however in R I get the "no sign change found error"

```
(-exp(-i*x))-x + 1
```

i = 1 in this case.

I'm plotting a graph where the value for i is 1:5. I've done this manually on excel and got a value of 0.003 when i = 1, here is the graph for all values of i: [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1ZI1.png)

When try to find the root for when i = 1 in R though I get the error.

This is the code I am using to find the root:

```
func1 <- function(x) {

  (-exp(-1*x))-x+1 
}

root <- uniroot(func1, lower =0.5, upper = 1, extendInt = "yes")
print(root)
print(root$root)

}
```

Plotting the equation when i = 1 gives the following curve: [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmR1S.png)

Looking at the curve it doesn't seem like f(x) crosses 0 which explains the error, however, I get a value in excel.

Any help on this would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The function has a zero for `x=0` and it's always negative for any other value. What do you get in excel?

Comment: I originally got 0.003 for when i =1, however, I didn't expanding on my trial and error method enough, after doing so it looks like the value is 2.512E-08

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I can offer. It is using a method of derivatives I found at http://rpubs.com/wkmor1/simple-derivatives-in-r. It will allow you to get the roots from newtons method.

```
options(scipen = 999)
f<-function(x) (-exp(-x)-x+1)
g<-function(x) { }
body(g)<-D(body(f),"x")
x <- 19
y<-vector()
y[1]<-x
for(i in 2:500) {
  y<-c(y, y[i-1] - (f(y[i-1])/g(y[i-1])))
  if(y[i]==y[i-1]) break
}
y
```

The output looks like this:

```
> y
 [1] 19.000000000000000  0.999999893546867  0.418023257075328  0.194491909332762
 [5]  0.094095681658666  0.046310116577025  0.022976345768161  0.011444180565743
 [9]  0.005711176200954  0.002852869974152  0.001425756748278  0.000712708975595
[13]  0.000356312158327  0.000178145499021  0.000089070105497  0.000044534390909
[17]  0.000022267031356  0.000011133470771  0.000005566723944  0.000002783342584
[21]  0.000001391644148  0.000000695821730  0.000000347990248  0.000000173795172
[25]  0.000000086916841  0.000000043487300  0.000000023063442  0.000000013435885
[29] -0.000000003090351 -0.000000003090351
```

I hope this helps.